# Delphi: FloatToStr and Single Type

Tags: delphi, floating-point

```pascal
var
    s: Single;
    d: Double;
begin
    d := 0.99;
    s := 0.99;

    ShowMessage(FloatToStr(d) + #13 + FloatToStr(s));
```

Result:

```
0,99
0,990000009536743
```

How to force right single type conversion to string, if you can't write your own function variation for single type?

Why can't? Delphi build SOAP objects from WSDL, and for `float` use `signle` type. And when convert value to XML text, use only standard FloatToStr function and result is like above. How to fix this without changing autogenerated code?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is (what does "force right single type" mean)? I see no strange behaviour at all in your example. If you don't want 15 digits after the decimal separator, you have to be explicit about that, such as `FormatFloat('0.##', s, TFormatSettings.Invariant);` or `FloatToStrF(s, ffGeneral, 3, 3, TFormatSettings.Invariant)`

Comment: In Delphi the standard `Soap.XSBuiltIns` unit use only `FloatToStr`. Cannot override this. When `THTTPRIO` (and buitlin conventer) build the XML from objects (base on RTTI) use exactly `FloatToStr` and nothing else for `Single` type.

Comment: Is it a problem if you get `0,990000009536743` instead of `0,99`? The difference is very, very small. And if XML is being built, surely you need to use period (`.`) as the decimal separator, and not comma (`,`)?

Comment: Yes, it is. Yes, in XML is dot, not coma. But precision is same.

Comment: I see. Then we'll wait to see what the SOAP/WSDL experts have to say about this.

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem. 0,99 cannot be expressed precisely as binary number. The single data type has a precision of about 7 digits, and 0,990000009536743 is probably the closest number to 0,99 that can be expressed in the single data type. In double you also cannot express 0,99 precisely, but with a precision of about 15 digits you don't see the difference if you print the first 15 digits. Do you have a problem with the precision of the single data type: Then you must use double. Or is it just an aesthetic problem with the printout?

Comment: @Matej but Delphi WSDL Importer translate float to Single. I know, that change to Double fix this problem, bo no one will remember the change type after imports in future. I want to avoid this. The WebService, that public WSDL, expects only 2 digits precision.

Comment: So use a formatting function to provide only two digits of precision.

Comment: The native `Soap.XSBuiltIns.SoapFloatToStr` funcion used by RTTI for this case use `FloatToStr` function, and the question is: how to change that? How can I overload this function without recompile native components and sources?

Comment: @Matej precision of about 7 digits is just a rule of thumb, and 0,990000009536743 is not the closest number to 0,99, it is 0.9900000095367431640625 for single and 0.9899999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375 for double.